# How to convert datetime format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z' in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string to datetime and keep getting the error:

ValueError: time data 'Sat, 14 May 2022 12:15:00 +0000' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'

```py
import datetime

format = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('Sat, 14 May 2022 12:15:00 +0000', format)
print(date)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It works perfectly on my machine. Are you sure that the code you posted is the same that you tried to execute?

Comment: A locale (language setting) issue maybe?

Comment: This code works on my laptop, but not on the Jupiter kernel. Is there a way to set up the locale?

Comment: @leebumseok you would use the locale module in the Python standard library.